# How to install a font in texlive 2017 (mac)?

Tags: installing-fonts

I'm running texlive 2017 on Mac OSX Sierra.

Could anyone tell me how to install a font? It was bought commercially some time ago, and is not available on the CTAN server so can't be installed using getnonfreefonts. I have .tfm, .pfb, .enc files and a .map file.

Answer (score 0):

Get the file "TeXLive2017+Changes.pdf.zip" from https://herbs.github.io and unzip it. There is a section of that document dedicated to installing fonts under the TeX Live distribution installed by MacTeX.