# MikTeX (Windows) to MAC OS (TeX Live)

Tags: fonts, texlive, linux

I processed a project under `Windows7, MIkTeX 2.9 (LaTeX)` and used `Bembo` font for the entire text. One of the co-author asked to make the file to run in `TeXLive` in a `Unix system` with the same font setup. I am not good in `Unix`, please suggest me how to install the fonts in `TeXLive` in a Unix system...

Comment: Can you ürovide a minimal example that shows what your font set-up looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed all my font related files into the `TL` installed path under the folder name `texmf-local` and run the following options:

```
sudo -H mktexlsr

sudo -H updmap-sys

sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=filename.map
```

Now the files works in Unix in a MAC system, thanks to `Jan` and `cfr` and also the following links:

[TeXLive- installing a Type - 1 font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265840/texlive-installing-a-type-1-font/266025#266025)

[How to install a font in texlive 2017 (mac)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381343/how-to-install-a-font-in-texlive-2017-mac)

Comment: My pleasure :-)  Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 2):

I am using TeXLive on MacOS.  Does that count as Unix system for you?

I have no clue about the Bembo fonts.  I suppose, you and your co-author have the same font at hand in order to install them on the Unix system.  Lets assume, it is called "bembo.otf".  I can't explain how to install it on the Unix system in more detail, as that depends on the system itself.

After having installed the font in the usual place, so that it can be found by alternative textprocessors, graphics applications, ..., LuaLaTeX from TeXLive will also find that font.

For you co-author, he needs to add

```latex
\usepackage{fontspec}
%% Setup the usage of Bembo as default font.
\setmainfont{bembo.otf}
```

That should do the trick.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, is it possible to run the file in `LaTeX` instead of `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi it depends on.  How do you run `LaTeX` with your document?  Is there a package, that you load with `\usepackage{bembo}`?  TeXLive offers package `fbb.sty`with a "Bembo like Font"

Comment: Unfortunately, If you intend to use `LaTeX`, you have to be prepared to do a  lot of complicated steps in the right order, to install your font file, font definitions, ... in the correct places, have to instruct the TeX system to find and understand them correctly, ... This is more less independent from the platform you are using (GNU/Linux, MacOS, Windows) or the TeX-System (MikTeX/TeXLive).  In general: what you could do with LaTeX on MikTeX you can do with LaTeX an TeXLive just by copying the needed file from your system to the TeXLive of your friend.

Comment: All the images are in EPS format, so only I am staying on `LaTeX`, hope you can understand the situation where I lies... :-(

Comment: You missed a lot of important details in your question ;-).  Correct me, when I got your comment wrong.  You intend to use good old LaTeX, producing DVI files and being capable to include EPS graphic files.  In that case, your colleague could still run `dvilualatex`.  This will act similar to your `latex` and won't complain about EPS files, but its Lua-Engine will use the Bembo font out of the box.  Sounds perfect to me.

Comment: @MadyYuvi If you can process your file with `latex` successfully with MikTeX on Windows and use Bembo font, then you can do so with Texlive on OS X/Linux/other system. Can you show us how you configure the fonts in the document?